# Angular 5/Implementing ngx carousel

Tags: angular, data-binding, carousel

I am running Angular 5.2.4 and installed ngx-carousel `"ngx-carousel": "^1.3.5"`

What I have:

```
<ngx-carousel class="banner" [inputs]="carouselBanner" (carouselLoad)="carouselBannerLoad()">
<ngx-item NgxCarouselItem *ngFor="let tile of carouselBannerItems; let i = index;">
    <div class="bannerStyle" [style.background]="'url(' + tile + ')'">
        <h1>{{i}}</h1>
    </div>
</ngx-item>
<button NgxCarouselPrev class="leftRs">&lt;</button>
<button NgxCarouselNext class="rightRs">&gt;</button>
```

I have a template parse errors in the console saying:

```
Can't bind to 'inputs' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-carousel'.
```

1. If 'ngx-carousel' is an Angular component and it has 'inputs' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please see this hope this will be help you :https://github.com/sheikalthaf/ngx-carousel/issues/61

Comment: @Nasri: Which version of this library are you using?

Comment: @NayeemMansoori it works in an empty project but when i tried to implement it in another project it gaves me this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import NgxCarouselModule to your module.
Then the issue will be solved.

In your module, add in imports section.

Answer (score 0):

In app.module.ts add
`import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/carousel';`

then in imports add
`CarouselModule.forRoot()`

You are not importing the modules in the main app.module.ts, thus getting error.